# How to use CMD regex to limit output in recursive directory search

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I need to create a dynamic report for a set of folders in a code repository that are inconsistently stored; some have the key feature two levels down, some three, and a few are four+ levels down.

- The closest thing to consistency that **all** of the key folders I need to
  report on contain either "*[...]d_d[...]*" or "*[...]dd_dd[...]*" (where d is a numeric digit); these matched strings may occur in the middle or at the end, but will never occur at the beginning.
- Once found, I need to list **only** the key folder and **not** any of its
  subfolders, even if one or more of its subfolders also happen to also
  contain either of the same patterns.
- because of the way the recursive listing is generated, all results will have a terminating slash, but I do not want to get anything beyond that slash; I honestly don't care if the terminating slash is part of the report or not.
- because of the inconsistencies, there may be three, four, five, or possibly more slashes in the **valid** output.

Here is a short example of a few instances where I need the results prefixed with **+++** and need to **not** include the listings prefixed with **---**

```
+++ A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R71_00_00/
--- A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R71_00_00/QR-HIJ-Outbound-123-Svc/SharedResources/WXYZ/Client/TU4_987_864X22Dat/
+++ A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R72_00_00/
--- A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R72_00_00/QR-HIJ-Outbound-123-Svc/SharedResources/WXYX/Client/TU4_987_864X22Dat/
+++ A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R73_00_00_WidgetMod/
--- A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R73_00_00_WidgetMod/QR-HIJ-Outbound-123-Svc/
+++ D4E5F6/QRWidgetFlow_R_1_0_0_DMND0903212-ErrorReports/
```

I've tried several variants on this

```
findstr /e /r /c:"[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][^0-9/]*/" /c:"[0-9]_[0-9][^0-9/]*/"
```

but each time I change it around, I either gain extra subfolders or lose key folders I had before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "tempfile=%tmp%\afilename"
SET "numerics=0-9"
SET "lastkey=?"

(FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%e IN (*_*) DO ECHO %%e)>"%tempfile%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('sort "%tempfile%"') DO (
 FOR %%y IN ("%%e\.") do (
  rem does leaf pass test does not start 9_9 or 99_99 
  ECHO %%~nxy|FINDSTR /b /r /c:"[%numerics%]_[%numerics%]" /c:"[%numerics%][%numerics%]_[%numerics%][%numerics%]">NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   rem does not start 9_9 or 99_99 - does it contain 9_9 or 99_99 ?
   ECHO %%~nxy|FINDSTR /r /c:"[%numerics%]_[%numerics%]" /c:"[%numerics%][%numerics%]_[%numerics%][%numerics%]">NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    rem contains 9_9 or 99_99
    CALL :report "%%e"
   )
  )
 )
)

DEL "%tempfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:report
SET "reportme=%~1"
SET "reportme=!reportme:%lastkey%=!"
IF "%reportme%" neq %1 GOTO :eof
ECHO %~1
SET "lastkey=%~1"
GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Obtain a full subdirectory list and store it in a tempfile.

Read each directoryname from a sorted version of the tempfile, and derive the leafname. If the leafname does not start with the target strings, but does contain one of the strings, then it's a candidate to be reported.

The report sees whether the quoted directoryname passed as `%1` contains the last-reported name. If it does, ignore it, otherwise report it and set it as the last-reported name.

Since the names are sorted, all subdirectories of a "key" directory will follow that directory in the list.

I believe that the strings to match may actually need to be _9_9 or _99_99 as 9_9 on its own would match "A1B2C3/ABC_Core/ABC_HIJ_R7xxxxx/QR-HIJ-Outbound-123-Svc/SharedResources/WXYZ/Client/TU**4_9**87_864X22Dat/"

Comment: In reverse order: 1) {prefixing _ }: good catch, thank you. I'll prob prefix the "_" and also suffix a "[\.\_]" since it will always be followed by either another naming element or file ext; 2) {code translation): thank you! This is extra helpful with answers involving regex; I wish more folks did this consistently; and 3) {actual code}: it looks visually/conceptually good, and I will test it out later today. If it does what I need, you'll get the check